# Problemas al redireccionar a funcion en controlador laravel

Tags: laravel, vistas

estoy intentando redireccionar usando un boton en laravel hacia el controlador en la funcion update, ya que quiero que al presionar el boton se cambie el valor de un campo especifico dentro de la BD, pero me da un error de "Missing required parameters for"
este es el codigo de la vista

```
@foreach($join as $joins)
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{action('controlSistema@update', $joins->id)}}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span></a>
@endforeach
```

y este el codigo del controlador

```
    public function update($id)
    {
        $actualizar=Caso::select($id)
                    ->where('id', '=', $id)
                    ->update([
                        'EstatusCaso' => 'Cerrado'
                    ]);
        return redirect()->route('sistema.index')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Tambien necesito obtener los datos de la persona del caso y eso esta enlazado con una llave foranea a los datos del caso y para poder mostrarlos intento hacer un inner join pero no me funciona me da error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

```
        $soli=Dato::select('CodSoli')->where('id', '=', $id);
        $soli2='DatosSoli'.$soli;
        $caso=Caso::select('Casos.EstatusCaso')->join('DatosSoli','Casos.CodSoli','=',$soli2);
```

Comment: No sé com ofunciona en laravel, pero en symfony hay un profiler que te dice el error y en qué linea, etc. En ese código que has puesto, en qué linea te está dando el error?

Comment: ya logre solucionar eso, es que en el arreglo no estaba llamando el campo id, pero ahora no me ejecuta la funcion update

Comment: Además no es recomendable una petición GET para actualizar la BD. Te conviene hacer un form con una petición PATCH para seguir las convenciones. Tendrás que tener definida la ruta.

Comment: tendra que se, porque de todas formas me da error en el show al hacerlo asi